# Get error Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when setting Wordpress on amazon ec2

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-ec2, server, mysqladmin

I have a problem when I setting up wordpress on amazon ec2, but I'm getting an issue about 'Access denied'.

```
[root@ip-172-31-25-142 ec2-user]# mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

[root@ip-172-31-25-142 ec2-user]# mysqladmin -u root -p password 6k8zJHLrmWB8bmwV

Enter password:

mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
```

Anyone can help me! Many thank!!!!

Comment: did you check database username password and username correct?

Comment: Thank all! I solved my problem by reset password!